# Delete rows in CSV file after being read by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I want to have 1 script writing continually to a CSV file, and another script reading periodically from that same CSV file.

What I'm looking for is a way to delete the rows I've just read in from the CSV file (not from my pandas dataframe).

Can anybody help?

```
# Read data in to dataframe
deviceInfo = pd.read_csv("sampleData.csv", nrows = 100)

# Somehow delete those 100 rows from the CSV file
```

Answer (score 1):

@JoseAngelSanchez is correct that you might want to read the whole `csv` into a dataframe, but I think this way lets you get a dataframe with the first 100 rows and still delete them from the `csv` file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sampleData.csv")

deviceInfo = df.iloc[:100]

df.iloc[100:].to_csv("sampleData.csv")
```

Note: if you're doing this repetitively then you'll probably want to write `to_csv(...,index=None)` or a new index column will be created in the `.csv` file on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the whole document and then delete the rows you don't want

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("sampleData.csv")

df = df.iloc[100:]

df.to_csv("sampleData.csv")
```